# Crystal Report formula to reset a count?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

[image]

I want to get the total qty of items sold by year by each part number. So far I have the following formula:

```
if {INVOICE_DATE} >= DateTime(2012, 01, 01) and 
   {INVOICE_DATE} <= DateTime(2012, 12, 31) 
THEN Sum ({INVOICE_QTY)
```

Now, that formula just sums all the parts sold in that year. What I need is for it to reset the sum as it count through each invoice and by each part. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is not doing what you think it is. For each row in your report (I'll assume that this is by an Invoice_ID or something along those lines) this will simply display the grand total sum of {INVOICE.QTY} for *all invoices in the report* and will not change from row to row.

To get something that is like your image, you need to create a Cross-Tab object and configure it such that its rows are based on the Product_ID, the columns are based on Invoice_Date and set to be printed "for each year", and set the "Summarized Fields" to be the sum of {INVOICE.QTY}.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not grouoing the report hence you are getting the grand total using that formula. What you can do is:

1. First create a group by `Year` and then by `Part`.
2. In details place your fields that need to be summed and supress the detail part.
3. Take sum in group footer 2 (`For parts summary`) and Group footer 1 (`For year summary`).